# UpdatePanel output not displaying

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have several pages on my site that use UpdatePanel and everything has been working fine until the last release I made, and now I have an odd problem.  On one page only, on the production site only, the output from an UpdatePanel postback is not being rendered.  Everything works perfectly in development and UAT, and every other page using update panel works fine in production.

I've used Fiddler to check what is going on, and after clicking a link I can see the reply coming back with the correct new page contents, but the display is not being updated.  I have a DevExpress ASPxLoadingPanel during the postback, so what the user sees is the Please Wait animation and this never goes away; I removed this just in case it was causing the problem, but that doesn't help - instead it just looks like nothing happens when you click a link, even though Fiddler shows the postback happens, and the reply comes back.

Since the problem only happens on the production site, and I've been unable to reproduce it anywhere else, debugging is a challenge.

Has anyone seen behaviour like this before, or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tracked down the problem - the minimised version of jquery-ui was slightly corrupted, and somehow this had no effect except on this one page; restoring the correct version solved the problem.